# Ofuscated code is not working when moved to server

Tags: asp.net, web, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I am working on a .NET project for obfuscation of code I use dotfuscator . i obfuscate the code very well.
But when a paste my obfuscated .Dll files to server it stop working and give forbidden error.
Image is attached for reference.

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem , how to obfuscate the code that work well

Comment: The easiest solution is to *not* use obfuscation. Obfuscation isn't a security measure, it's a way to prevent others from stealing your code using a decompiler. Very few applications have anything worth stealing. Obfuscation almost never worth the trouble. Besides, the vendors selling obfuscators typically sell *de*obfuscators to allow debugging of obfuscated code.

Comment: If your code contains passwords or other sensitive information, the solution is to *remove* them from the code and save them eg in configuration files protected by permissions and possibly encrypted by the OS or ASP.NET. NTFS provides file encryption. ASP.NET allows encrypting sections of `web.config` to protect eg database connection strings

Comment: First deploy the unobfuscated version of your application, to see if the error persists. If the error is still there, the reason is _not_ obfuscation